# Editing options presented on top of header in UITableView, iOS 11

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, header

When I swipe to delete, the "Delete" option is presented on top of section header. Did anyone have the same problem in iOS 11? In iOS10 everything works ok.
Here is the image:
[Image that shows problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OL4ti.png)

I made new project, and here is my code for VC. It has only the table view. I am not sure what is different in iOS 11, and what should be done differently..

Here is the code for ViewController:
class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 30
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Test"

    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 40))
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    return view // I tried returning view.contentView, it didn't help
}
// Override to support editing the table view.
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}
```

}